# Excel Macro: Find and Compare Username from a Range of Authorized Usernames

Tags: excel, vba, object, date-range

Excel Macro: How to code this "If username [example code: Environ("Username")] is equal to one of the values within this range [example: Range I created from a workbook: Range("Authorized_Users")] then..." Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to do exactly what you have written. What currently is missing for your solution are two things:

1. A way to retrieve the user name.
2. A way to search in a range.

Both tasks should't be that hard because excel already offer some great functions to do so.

For the second point, you would have to create a function, that searches a range. The find in range function would look something like this:

```
Function ExistsInRange(range As range, name As String) As Boolean
    ExistsInRange = False
    Dim resultRange As range
    If Trim(name) <> "" Then
        With range
            Set resultRange = .Find(What:=name, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not resultRange Is Nothing Then
                ExistsInRange = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

If you want to search all rows in Column B for the user name "jeff", the call would look something like this:

```
If ExistsInRange( sheet.Range("B:B"), "jeff") Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Your spec is so close to the required code...

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Environ("Username"), [Authorized_Users], 0)) Then
```